# Change menu item after selection in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to replace the menu item to another menu item after selection. I tried the following but it is not working as expected. Any solutions to this. thanks.

The menu.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/add" android:visible="true" android:enabled="true" android:title="Add"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/delete" android:visible="false" android:enabled="true" android:title="Delete"></item>
</menu>
```

The code inside MyActivity.java is:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.defaultmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        if(isAdded) {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.add);
            menu.add(0, R.id.delete, 0, "Delete");
        } else {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.delete);
            menu.add(0, R.id.add, 0, "Add");
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                isLogin = true;
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                isLogin = false;
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific "It is not working as expected"?

Comment: @Kaediil: "Add" menu is displayed 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

To refresh your menu call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`
And i guess in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, you can do..

```
if(isAdded) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.add).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.delete).setVisible(true);
        return true;
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.add).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.delete).setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Careful of the subtle difference in menus in Android 3.0+, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html look for the "handling click events" section. Android 3.0+ requires invalidateOptionsMenu() to refresh, I believe this will crash the app before 3.0.

Comment: @Nunu: No it's not working. When I write `menu.clear();` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, It's working but other menu options also clears. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public static final int ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX = Menu.FIRST;
public static final int DELETE_CATEGORY_INDEX= Menu.FIRST+1;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX, 0, "Add");
          menu.add(0, DELETE_CATEGORY_INDEX, 0, "delete");

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX:             
        break;
    }
            case DELETE_CATEGORY_INDEX:          
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it simply displays the 2 menu otions Add and Delete. I want only One to be visible at a time. Initially Add will be displayed with other menu options. When User clicked that "Add" menu option, it will change to "Delete" menu option. This is the requirement.

Comment: It feels strange that you have call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); before editing the menu, I would think you would edit the menu and pass that to the super, but I would be wrong. :/

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, now it's working fine.

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //menu.clear();
        if(isadded) {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.add);
            menu.removeItem(R.id.delete);
            menu.add(0, R.id.delete, 0, "Delete");
        } else {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.add);
            menu.removeItem(R.id.delete);
            menu.add(0, R.id.add, 0, "Add");
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```